# If there any problem if i format my Old C drive?

Tags: formatting

Firstly i have 1 TB HDD & now i put external SSD of 256 GB & extend RAM from 4 to 8 GB  So firstly my C drive is 470 GB & Now that old C drive is new D drive with storage of 470 GB & the SSD of 256 GB is new C drive

So my question is that if i fromat that new D drive of 470 GB which is older C drive

Answer (score 0):

If the windows you are booting is now actually installed on your new C drive, and you have nothing you care about on your D drive you can go ahead and format it

Comment: How to check that my windows is booting on C drive?